# Scraping content with inner HTML using simple_html_dom

Tags: php, xml, web-scraping

I am using `simple_html_dom.php` to scrape data from HTML website, and write it into XML format. The following is the HTML source example of data the script scrapes.

```
<h3>Background</h3>
<ol>
   <li><strong>Text here</strong>The text here text text text</li>
   <li>The text here text text <br/> text</li>
</ol>
<p>Text here</p>
<h3>Job Description</h3>
```

The following lines scrape only the content (text) and ignores the HTML elements, like: `<ol>, <li>, <br/>`

```
$html = file_get_html($url) ;
$xmlPageDom = new DomDocument();
@$xmlPageDom->loadHTML($html);
$xmlPageXPath = new DOMXPath($xmlPageDom);

$value1 = $xmlPageXPath->query('//text()[preceding::h3[text()="Background"] and following-sibling::h3[text()="Job Description"]]');
$value2 = $xmlPageXPath->query('//node()[preceding::h3[text()="Background"] and following-sibling::h3[text()="Job Description"]]/node()');
$tag = "background";        
$XML .= createXMLtags($tag,nodelists2string($value1, $value2));

function nodelist2string($nodelist){
        $result="";
        foreach($nodelist as $node){
            $result.="<".$node->nodeName.">";
            if ($node->hasChildNodes()){
                $result.=nodelist2string($node);
            }
            $result.=$node->nodeValue;
            $result.="</".$node->nodeName.">";
        }
        return $result;
}
    
function nodelists2string($nodelist1, $nodelist2){
    $result="";
    foreach($nodelist1 as $node){
        $result.="<".$node->nodeName.">";
        if ($node->hasChildNodes()){
            $result.=nodelist2string($node);
        }
        $result.=$node->nodeValue;
        $result.="</".$node->nodeName.">";
    }
    foreach($nodelist2 as $node){
        $result.="<".$node->nodeName.">";
        if ($node->hasChildNodes()){
            $result.=nodelist2string($node);
        }
        $result.=$node->nodeValue;
        $result.="</".$node->nodeName.">";
    }
    return $result;
}
```

How can I scrape the text including the inner HTML? Currently, the script on scrape plain text. I also tried following `strip_tags`, and it works only for `<li>` and doesn't work for the rest of HTML elements.

```
$value=strip_tags($value,'<li>');
```

I tried `saveHTML` but couldn't figure it out, where exactly to add it.

Comment: I don't see where `simple_html_dom.php` is used in your code. The libraries you're using are probably `libxml` and `DOM`.

Comment: @f_martinez I am using `simple_html_dom.php` library. I have few lines more code in above which includes the mentioned library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating, I found that html source code is scrapping with the code. I used `echo $html;` and saw that all `innerhtml` content was there, but the following code was ignoring the html elements, and only scraping the plain text.

```
$value1 = $xmlPageXPath->query('//text()[preceding::h3[text()="Background"] and following-sibling::h3[text()="Job Description"]]');
$value2 = $xmlPageXPath->query('//node()[preceding::h3[text()="Background"] and following-sibling::h3[text()="Job Description"]]/node()');
$tag = "background";        
$XML .= createXMLtags($tag,nodelists2string($value1, $value2));
```

The, I used the `preg_replace` to find and replace the html tags with `html encoded entities`. After importing the content to my database, the `html entities` converted back to decoded version and the text appears in formatted form.

```
$html=preg_replace("/<br \/>/i",'&lt;br&gt;', $html)
```

I used the above line for each html element I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it can't be be done with simple html dom, but if you switch to [this one](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom) you can do:

```
$str = <<<EOF
<h3>Background</h3>
<ol>
   <li><strong>Text here</strong>The text here text text text</li>
   <li>The text here text text <br/> text</li>
</ol>
<p>Text here</p>
<h3>Job Description</h3>
EOF;

$html = str_get_html($str);

echo $html->text;
/* will output:
Background
Text hereThe text here text text text
   The text here text text  text
Text here
Job Description
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did this finally by encoding the `html` elements first.

Comment: Ok, I thought you might like my way better.